# Qual proveito tirar do life cycle do Jsf?

Tags: jsf

Pessoal eu vejo pessoas falando que se deve entender o ciclo de vida do JSF. E eu queria entender quais utilidades teremos ao entender?

Answer (score 2):

Como toda linguagem de programação, vc deve saber o básico de como ela funciona. JSF não é diferente mas não significa dizer que vc não consiga construir um sistema se não souber o seu ciclo de vida. Estudar-lo é apenas para saber como, quando e onde utilizar os recursos avançados dele. Se vc souber as respostas das questões abaixo significa que não precisa estudar o ciclo de vida. Vejamos:

1. Vc sabe quando a árvore do JSF não precisa ser renderizada ou quando os dados precisam ser mantidos na página caso aconteça algum problema?
2. Vc sabe quando os métodos SET são chamados, ou seja, quando os valores são atualizados?
3. Vc sabe quando são realizados os processos de validações? Sabe quando ele verifica se um campo é obrigatório ou quando seu validador personalizado é executado?
4. Vc sabe quando a ação originada de um botão ou link clicado é executada?
5. E, por último, vc sabe quando tudo que foi pedido pra ser feito, e processado com sucesso, é apresentado?

Se vc souber as respostas pra essas e outras questões, como saber que o **immediate** em um componente de ação faça com que alguns ciclos de vidas sejam ignorados, pode ajudar e muito em certos casos.

**Obs.: O escopo utilizado influencia e muito no ciclo de vida** assim, além de estudar o ciclo, estude os escopos.

Comment: Bacana sua resposta, eu realmente não sei atualmente responder todas. Mas minha curiosidade partiu porque vejo muito a se falar disso e também de um problema outro dia que surgiu de certos métodos serem chamados a todo momento quando se esta carregando a página.

Comment: @Macario1983 é por esses motivos que muita gente recomenda estudar-lo. Boa sorte!

Comment: Cara você recomenda algum material para ler.?

Comment: @Macario1983, acho que é proibido recomendar coisas aqui mas, arriscando, eu recomendo o Core JavaServer Faces - David Geary. Esse é excelente!